# How to stop language bar from moving

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, language-bar

I've run into the following problem after one of the recent updates, current system version is 19041.867

Previously, the language bar was to the left of the system tray icons for all languages, in a fixed position, like so: [correct position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPXpd.png). However, after the update, it keeps resetting itself into [this position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEqmT.png) - only for Japanese language - while other languages remain on the left as in the first picture.

Because of it, not only is it hard to click any given icon (since the language is different from window to window, it starts jumping around if the language isn't the same in the taskbar and the window I'm going from), but I also unintentionally move icons around since it happens instantly during mouse click.

As far as I understand, it relies on [this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmWwi.png) (the last checkbox), as the Japanese bar fixes itself if I enable the language bar checkbox, but as soon as I switch from and back to Japanese, it is reset into the position on the right. Is there any way to make this setting stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into this same problem, the way I fixed it was to revert the Microsoft IME to the old version.